# IF with no test flags?

Tags: bash, if-statement, logic

I don't understand how to read this properly. This is an IF statement without any kind of test flags, so I don't understand the logic ... help?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    get_user_input() {
      if [[ $1 ]]; then
        use_default=1
      else
        use_default=
      fi
```

I understand that this is a function. I understand that its calling for the first positional argument ($1), but I don't understand why its in an IF statement, if they aren't testing for anything.

I've been tasked to rewrite a script from a vendor, and they have stuff like this all over the place. I'm thinking that maybe they've just purposefully over complicated things for job security?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man bash`, under *CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS*:

```
string
-n string
    True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

So this is the same as `[[ -n $1 ]]` (though clearly less readable to those familiar with other shells). Personally, I would suggest that you use `[[ -n $1 ]]` to make the desired behaviour explicit.

If you're interested in making the script more portable, you should go for `[ -n "$1" ]`.

Answer (score 1):

Better than using the `if` statement is to use the following parameter expansion:

```
use_default=${1:+1}
```

If `$1` has a non-null value, `use_default` is set to 1; otherwise, it gets the null value resulting from the expansion of `$1`.